# undefined local variable or method `contact'

Tags: ruby

```
NameError in Contacts#index
Showing C:/mycontact/app/views/contacts/index.html.erb where line #43 raised:

undefined local variable or method `contact' for #<#<Class:0x3b7eee0>:0x3b7c738>
Rails.root: C:/mycontact
```

Below is the index.html.erb file:

```
<div class="panel panel-default">
        <table class="table">

            <% @contacts.each do |contact| %>


          <tr>
            <td class="middle">
              <div class="media">
                <div class="media-left">
                  <a href="#">
                    <img class="media-object" src="http://placehold.it/100x100" alt="...">
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="media-body">
                    <h4 class="media-heading"><%= contact.name %></h4>
                  <address>
                    <strong><%= contact.company %></strong><br>
                      <%= contact.email %>
                  </address>
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td width="100" class="middle">
              <div>
                  <%= link_to edit_contact_path(contact), class: "btn btn-circle btn-default btn-xs", title: "Edit" do %>
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
                  <% end %>
                  <%= link_to contact_path(contact), :method => :delete, class: "btn btn-circle btn-danger btn-xs", title: "Delete" , data: { confirm: "Are you sure?"} do %>
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
                  <% end %>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>

            <% end %>

          <tr>
            <td class="middle">
              <div class="media">
                <div class="media-left">
                  <a href="#">
                      <%= image_tag contact.avatar.url(:thumb), class: "media-object" %>
                  </a>
                </div>
                <div class="media-body">
                  <h4 class="media-heading">Contact 2</h4>
                  <address>
                    <strong>Job 2</strong><br>
                    contact2@sample.com
                  </address>
                </div>
              </div>
            </td>
            <td width="100" class="middle">
              <div>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-circle btn-default btn-xs" title="Edit">
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></i>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-circle btn-danger btn-xs" title="Edit">
                  <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i>
                </a>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>            
      </div>
      <div class="text-center">
          <%= will_paginate %>
      </div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read "[ask]" and "[mcve]". You're missing important information, such as a question about what the problem is. We can guess what it is, but you still need to ask it in the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

`<%= image_tag contact.avatar.url(:thumb), class: "media-object" %>` is not in the loop anymore as you ended above that, so contact is undefined.

To fix it you should move your `<% end %>` to the end of the file.

Comment: to the end of which file please can you please demonstrate

Comment: thank you i solved it i put the <% end %> at the end of the file